# RequireJS - exclude by directory (or regex)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

This is a portion of my build configuration for requireJS's optimizer, r.js.

```
exclude: [
    'widgets/cr-log-display',
    'widgets/cr-pager',
    'widgets/cr-time-input'
```

My question is simply this: is it possible to exclude ALL dependencies starting with `widgets/`.

The docs don't seem to indicate that a regex, or anything similar can be passed here.  Is there another configuration parameter that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you cannot pass a regular expression to `exclude`. I'm saying this from having read the source of `r.js`. The processing of `exclude` uses an internal function named `findBuildModule`, which compares what is passed to `exclude` against module names with `===`. And by the same token, there is no way to tell `r.js` "exclude all modules under this directory".

The one avenue I see you might be able to use is `onBuildWrite`, which is a global setting that takes a function. I've used it for other purposes than what you want but perhaps this would do the trick:

```
onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    return /^widgets\//.test(moduleName) ? "" : contents;
}
```

If the module name starts with `widgets/` then the contents that will be written to the bundle will be the empty string, otherwise the contents will be whatever the module's contents happen to be.

Note that this *will not* do *exactly* what `exclude` does. The `exclude` setting excludes the listed modules *and* their dependencies. The `onBuildWrite` example above is an analogue to `excludeShallow` in that the modules that match the regular expression will be excluded but their dependencies won't be excluded. There is no way to easily write an `onBuildWrite` function that will extend the exclusion to dependencies of the modules that you'd like to exclude. `r.js` does not give an API to query dependencies of a module.